# How to check the current values of apache(passenger) variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am running rails applications on Apache with Passenger.

How do I get the values of apache variables related to Passenger like PassengerMaxPoolSize and PassengerPoolIdleTime?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this in the past with good luck. It does not give you exactly what you are after, but it might point you in the right direction:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { `passenger-memory-stats` }
Bundler.with_clean_env { `rvmsudo passenger-status` }
```

Comment: I ran the command in console and got an error "command not found:". How did you do that?

Comment: What was the command that was not found? Was it rvmsudo? you might not need that I only used that command because it was part of a deploy that used RVM.